# Autofill text field in a Modal Dialog pop up in WebView (Android App)

Tags: android, modal-dialog, android-webview, autofill

I have an Android App in which I need to implement auto-read and auto-fill of OTP (via SMS). The main work in the app is done by a Web application which the App calls via **WebView**.
I have been able to read the OTP value which is received by SMS (by implementing **SMS Receiver, SMS Listener** etc as explained in other stackoverflow articles)
I now need to autofill the parsed OTP into the OTP Text box.

[This is the (WebView)page where I enter the mobile number to receive the OTP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVtmu.png)

When I click on Generate OTP this dialog pops up:
[Modal Dialog to input OTP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMUhT.png)

I need to autofill the OTP Text field and autoclick on the submit button, so that my Web Application can validate the OTP. How can I do this?

Comment: did u find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I just have one approach but If someone already did this then please let me know your approach.

Read the SMS from native app code then expose to web view so that JavaScript can read from window object. You can create a waiting function in JavaScript to read a globally exposed variable from App bridge. Once to get some valid value fill it in the otp text box and clear the value in the global variable.